# Cannot read file as binary in python 2.7

Tags: python, file

```
file = open("images.jpeg", "rb")

c = file.read(512)
print(type(c))
print(c)

file.close()
```

c is a str object. Shouldn't it be a bytes object? According to doc, it should be!

In Python 3.2, it is really a bytes object. What happened in Python2.7?

Platform: Kubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Comment: What problem is this causing you?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I want to analyse image file format, get the file header and raw data. How to operate on str object?

Comment: Use the `struct` module to "Interpret strings as packed binary data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes` is an alias for `str` in Python 2.7

Comment: Maybe the OP should convert the bytes (str) read in into a [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=bytes#bytearray).